# Divide the column by the sum grouped by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, sum

I have a table like this

```
source   |  destination   | frequency
-------------------------------------
   a     |       b        |     4
   a     |       c        |     2
   b     |       c        |     1
   b     |       a        |     3
```

and I would like to divide the `frequency` by the sum of `frequency` grouped by the `source`. Therefore, I am looking for a table like

```
source   |  destination   | frequency
-------------------------------------
   a     |       b        |     4/6
   a     |       c        |     2/6
   b     |       c        |     1/4
   b     |       a        |     3/4
```

Is there any way to do this in a single sql query?

Comment: Can you potentially create a new field that calculates the sum for each row - then just do simple division with a group by 'source'? That may not be a single query approach but initial thoughts

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` window function.

If you want a numerical result:

```
SELECT source, destination,
       frequency / SUM(frequency) OVER(PARTITION BY source)
FROM tablename
```

Depending on your database, if it performs integer division between integers, you may need to multiply by 1.0:

```
SELECT source, destination,
       1.0 * frequency / SUM(frequency) OVER(PARTITION BY source)
FROM tablename
```

If you want the result as a string you can do it with concatenation:

```
SELECT source, destination,
       CONCAT(frequency, '/', SUM(frequency) OVER(PARTITION BY source))
FROM tablename
```

I used `CONCAT()`, but if your database does not support it use its concatenation operator and also you may need to convert the integer values to strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum over`

```
select *, frequency /  Sum(frequency) over(partition by source)  
from table
```

If `frequency` is an `int`, multiply by 1.0 or `cast/convert` to get a decimal result.

Answer (score 0):

For a single query, you can use `join`:

```
select t.source, t.destination, t.frequency/sum(t1.frequency) from testtable t join testtable t1 on t1.source = t.source group by t.source, t.destination
```